# Why 2 select arrow are appearing in Asp List Box

Tags: html, css, asp.net

While uploading to the server, I am getting two select drop down arrows in my drop down list. Why?  I am using a multi select list box list.

I am using multi select List Box

**Inspecting Code for one List Item:** (Chrome)
[image]

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected"><span class="multiselect-selected-text">None selected</span> <b class="caret"></b></button>
    <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
        <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all"><a tabindex="0" class="multiselect-all"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="multiselect-all">  Select all</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="UAE"><input type="checkbox" value="150"> UAE</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="OMAN"><input type="checkbox" value="160"> OMAN</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="CENTRAL"><input type="checkbox" value="200"> CENTRAL</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="WEST"><input type="checkbox" value="350"> WEST</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="SOUTH"><input type="checkbox" value="400"> SOUTH</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="EAST"><input type="checkbox" value="600"> EAST</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="QATAR"><input type="checkbox" value="720"> QATAR</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="BAHRAIN"><input type="checkbox" value="730"> BAHRAIN</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="KUWAIT"><input type="checkbox" value="740"> KUWAIT</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="NORTH"><input type="checkbox" value="800"> NORTH</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="EXPORT"><input type="checkbox" value="500"> EXPORT</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="HEAD OFFICE"><input type="checkbox" value="900"> HEAD OFFICE</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="RENDERING"><input type="checkbox" value="910"> RENDERING</label></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox" title="PREMIER FOOD EXPORT"><input type="checkbox" value="801"> PREMIER FOOD EXPORT</label></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My code**

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=ddlregion]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=ddlDepot]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

**I tried :** (For removing default select Arrow)

```
    .css {
        /* for Firefox */
        -moz-appearance: none;
        /* for Chrome */
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

as i can see in inspect when i remove class 1 arrow is not appearing

[image]

**drop down**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlregion" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="css"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlregion_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataTextField="REGION_DESC" 
    DataValueField="REGION_CODE"
    runat="server" 
    SelectionMode="Multiple" 
    ValidationGroup="Region">
        
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlDepot" Width="220px" runat="server" 
    CssClass="css" 
    DataValueField="DEPOT_CODE" 
    SelectionMode="Multiple">
```

[image: Click]

Please help me why i am getting two select arrow in drop down list ?

Comment: Have you looked at the content of ::after pseudo-element?

Comment: Maybe the arrow is there too? https://prnt.sc/v6vjfo

Comment: @LaurentC what i need to check in ::after pseudo-element as i can check in ::after but nothing is appearing in :: after

Comment: well if it contains an arrow image?

Comment: while removing <b class=""></b> its showing only one arrow but how can i remove this class value in my code ?

Comment: @LaurentC No nothing is showing in ::after Please check my updated question i have added screen shots of ::after

Comment: ok well i would need to see the full code because clearly somethin is injecting an arrow and something else too

Comment: ok fine Please check my updated code once again